# react-virtualized - calling public methods on Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'd like to access the public method [recomputeGridSize](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#recomputegridsize--columnindex-number-rowindex-number-) on one of the `Grid`s that I'm rendering. I've created the `ref` but when I try call the method it appears that the method is not available.

See below where the ref is defined in the final `Grid`:

```
render() {
    const { structure, columnHeaderIndex, variables } = this.props;
    const {
      sidebarWidth,
      headerHeight,
      headerRowCount,
      height,
      gridHeight,
      gridWidth
    } = variables;
    const rowCount = structure.length;
    const columnCount = columnHeaderIndex.length;

    if (structure.length === 0 || columnCount.length === 0) return null;

    console.log(this.bodyGrid);

    return (
      <div>
        <ScrollSync>
          {({
            clientHeight,
            clientWidth,
            onScroll,
            scrollHeight,
            scrollLeft,
            scrollTop,
            scrollWidth
          }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div
                  className="LeftSideGridContainer"
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    borderBottom: '1px solid black',
                    color: 'white'
                  }}
                >
                  <Grid
                    cellRenderer={this.renderLeftHeaderCell}
                    className="header-grid"
                    width={sidebarWidth + 1}
                    columnWidth={sidebarWidth + 1}
                    height={headerHeight}
                    rowHeight={headerHeight}
                    rowCount={1}
                    columnCount={1}
                  />
                </div>
                <div
                  className="LeftSideGridContainer"
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: headerHeight,
                    left: 0,
                    borderTop: '1px solid black',
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    color: 'black'
                  }}
                >
                  <Grid
                    cellRenderer={this.renderLeftSideCell}
                    columnWidth={sidebarWidth + 1}
                    columnCount={1}
                    className="left-side-grid"
                    height={height}
                    rowHeight={gridHeight}
                    rowCount={rowCount}
                    scrollTop={scrollTop}
                    width={sidebarWidth + 1}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="grid-column">
                  <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                    {({ width }) =>
                      <div>
                        <div
                          style={{
                            height: headerHeight,
                            width: width - scrollbarsize(),
                            overflow: 'hidden'
                          }}
                        >
                          <Grid
                            className="header-grid"
                            cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
                            cellRangeRenderer={this.renderHeaderCells}
                            columnWidth={gridWidth}
                            columnCount={columnCount}
                            height={headerHeight}
                            rowHeight={headerHeight / headerRowCount}
                            rowCount={headerRowCount}
                            scrollLeft={scrollLeft}
                            width={width - scrollbarsize()}
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div
                          style={{
                            height: height,
                            width: width,
                            borderLeft: '1px solid black',
                            borderTop: '1px solid black'
                          }}
                        >
                          <Grid
                            className="calendar-body"
                            cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
                            cellRangeRenderer={this.cellRangeRenderer}
                            columnWidth={gridWidth}
                            columnCount={columnCount}
                            height={height}
                            rowHeight={gridHeight}
                            rowCount={rowCount}
                            width={width}
                            onScroll={onScroll}
                            ref={ref => {
                              this.bodyGrid = ref;
                            }}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>}
                  </AutoSizer>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </ScrollSync>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And you can see that if I `console.log(this.bodyGrid)` that none of the public methods defined in the documentation are available:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the screenshot shows what you think it shows. The `Grid` API methods should be within a `__proto__` proprety further down:

[image]

Without seeing your full code it's not really possible to tell what's going on, but `Grid` definitely defines a method `recomputeGridSize`. The `CellMeasurer` component, for example, works by calling this method.

Comment: You're dead right @brianvaughn. I was expecting the public methods to be directly in the `bodyGrid` object - didn't realise they would be tucked away in `__proto__` property.

Furthermore I was getting an error when trying to call these methods because I was experimenting with it in the `render()` method and when it is called the first time `this.bodyGrid` is undefined, which was resulting in the error.

I've now been able to successfully call the methods by tucking calls in an if statement that checks that `this.bodyGrid` exists. As always, thanks heaps for your help. You're a powerhouse!

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it resolved! Yup, refs are null until the component's mounted initially. :)